# How to disable all "Allow paste from" prompts?

Tags: iphone, ios, security, privacy

When I open many apps, I get prompted

> "App" would like to paste from "Last app"
> Do you want to allow this?
> Don't Allow Paste
> Allow Paste

I always want to select "Don't Allow Paste"

How can I just prevent this prompt from appearing in the first place?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be configured in the app-specific part of Settings *if* the app supports it (otherwise you should contact the developer).

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know that. Is there a shortcut to make it Deny for all?

Comment: @theonlygusti I didn‘t know either, stumbled across it by chance. And AFAIK there is no global option.